# Google Sheets Formula For Wage Calculation

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

We are trying to work out a formula for paying our sales team. Basically they get paid a basic wage of £350 regardless of making any sales as a "safety net" or 40% of sales done up to £2000 (whichever is greater). So for example, £1000 sales = £400 commission, £500 sales = £350 commissions.

Essentially the £350 is there incase sales fall below £875 they are guaranteed to still get the £350.

It gets a little tricky for me when sales go over £2000 anything OVER £2000 they get 50% on. So for example £3000 sales they would get £800 on the first £2000 and £500 on the £1000 over the £2000. So total wages for that week would be £1,300. Some examples below:

```
Sales: £500 Pay = £350
Sales: £900 Pay = £360
Sales: £1500 Pay = £600 
Sales: £2500 Pay = £1,050
Sales: £4000 Pay = £1,800
```

Is there a formula I can use if i have the sales total of the sales agent, to calculate there wage automatically.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly short way of doing it

```
=MAX(350,0.4*A1+0.1*text(A1-2000,"0;\0"))
```

Otherwise perhaps more simply

```
=if(A1<875,350,if(A1<2000,A1*0.4,800+(A1-2000)*0.5))
```

Which can be simplified to

```
=IF(A1<875,350,IF(A1<2000,A1*0.4,0.5*A1-200))
```

Comment: Hi Tom, this worked perfect! Many thanks for this solution

Comment: That's great. Of course the second formula can be simplified so I'll add that to my answer.